# iOS 6.1 push notification beeps too many times

Tags: ios, notifications, push, beep

I have a very strange problem. Our iOS app uses the push notification, and our server is setup to push out the "event notification" to the mobile app for each new "event". This has been running really well until iOS 6.1 comes out.

In my testing, I use two iphone 5 deviecs: A on iOS 6.0, B on iOS 6.1.

When I tried to push multiple events to the devices (with a gap of 1 min), i see the following:

on device A: each push is individual,

```
 event 1: beep once 

 event 2: beep once

 event 3: beep once
```

on device B:

```
 event 1: beep once

 event 2: beep twice (if I never click on event 1)

 event 3: beep three times (if I never click on event 1 and 2)
```

This is very annoying, because if a user does not click on individual notification event, the number of beeps will accumulate very fast. It does not help even if user clears the events by going to the iphone 5 notification window, the last notification will bring the previous ones back, and beep multiple times.

Has any one seen a similar problem. On the server side, I am using apns.php download from here: http://www.easyapns.com/php-source. It has been working great in the past 2 years.